# AWS Cloudwatch alarms repeated notifications to slack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, slack

I'm successfully deployed solution described in AWS blog that enables repeated notifications on CloudWatch Alarms utilizing the alarm’s state change event via Amazon EventBridge and AWS Step Function.
There is a site which describe this:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-repeated-notification-cdk

It is able to send valid e-mail notifications, but the problem is to send it to Slack channel. I was overwhelmed by the problem of an incorrect message format being sent to a slack channel.
I'm looking for solution which can send repeated notification to Slack or how to change that code.

Comment: Have you set up an email address for the slack channel to send to? Or how do you try to send it?

Comment: For default I have configured two endpoints on my sns topics: https://global.sns-api.chatbot.amazonaws.com and e-mail address endpoint.
They work properly when alarms goes to red. But repeated notifications are sent successfully only to my email. There is no notification on slack.

Comment: Yeah but how is you endpoint to slack looking? Have you set up a e-mail for the channel you want to send you msg to?

Comment: I have http endpoints configured on sns topics subscriptions. I think problem is in python script here:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-repeated-notification-cdk/blob/main/lib/src/check_alarm_status_lambda/index.py
It's written to sent messages only to e-mail in 66 line:
`
 SNS_CLIENT.publish(
                            TopicArn = action,
                            Subject = notification_subject,
                            Message = json.dumps(alarm_details)
                        )
`
I don't know how to change this.

Comment: So the solution is to use a email endpoint to slack and have it as a subscriber to your sns topic